# How to evaluate date from a string

Tags: bash, shell, date, variables, ksh

Here are my files :

**conf.txt**

```
case1:fooYYYYmmdd.bar

case2:helloYYYYmmdd.world
```

**script.sh**

```
fname=`grep $1 conf.txt | cut -d ':' -f2`
```

When calling my `script.sh` with a parameter being `case1` or `case2`, I obviously get my var `fname` fed with `fooYYYYmmdd.bar` or `helloYYYmmdd.world`.

How could I evaluate the date from my `conf.txt` so `fname` would be set with `foo20181120.bar` and `hello20181120.world` without going through breaking and building back my string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just declare a `Date` variable and use it in `fname`, like this:

```
Date=$(date +%Y%m%d)

fname=$(grep $1 conf.txt |sed "s/YYYYmmdd/$Date/g"|cut -d ':' -f2)
echo $fname
```